# Load jar file dynamically and create spring beans using xml

Tags: java, spring, jar, classloader, urlclassloader

I have an application which gets deployed as `war` file in application server. I have a requirement of adding a new `jar` file at `runtime` without stopping the service. and later i will create beans from the bean `xml` definitions stored in database.

I have seen the solutions on internet which loads the classes with `URLClassLoader` and method invocation with a particular `classname`. But my requirement is to load classes and be able to create beans whenever i want without bothering about `classnames`.

Code which i have tried.

```
    String pathToJar = "/home/sample.jar";
    JarFile jarFile;
    List<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        jarFile = new JarFile(pathToJar);
        Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();
        URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + pathToJar + "!/") };
        URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls, AppzillonRestWS.class.getClassLoader());
        int i = 0;
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry je = e.nextElement();
            if (je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                continue;
            }
            String className = je.getName().substring(0, je.getName().length() - 6);
            className = className.replace('/', '.');
            Class c = cl.loadClass(className);
            if(className.contains("tbAsmi") && !className.contains("_PK")){
                classes.add(className);
                System.out.println(className);
            }
            i++;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        jarFile.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Later i am trying to create beans from the classes loaded from jar.

Upon calling on the bean i am  getting "`ClassNotFoundException`".

```
15:20:59,932 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/AppzillonServer].[jersey]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jersey threw exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iexceed.appzillon.services.Admin.ScreensQuery.ScreensQuery_Query_Service from [Module "deployment.AppzillonServer.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:247) [spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1348) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:362) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:466) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:459) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:79) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:55) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:331) [spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:252) [spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) [spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at com.iexceed.appzillon.domain.service.SecurityParamsService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c24d46e9.fetchSecurityParams(<generated>) [spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
at com.iexceed.appzillon.domain.DomainStartup.processRequest(DomainStartup.java:178) [appzillon-domain-3.5.16.jar:]
at com.iexceed.appzillon.rest.AppzillonRestWS.processRequest(AppzillonRestWS.java:143) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297) [jersey-common-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030) [jersey-server-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.12.jar:]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.12.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:420) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: It's best practice to post stacktrace with exception related questions, please consider adding it

Answer (score 0):

The reason happens ClassNotFoundException is that cannot find classes in Env or classpath, so first, make sure whether loaded the class.